# How to keep my own CR in Vim with automatic format?

Tags: vim

I used `set fo+=a` in Vim to enable automatic format when typing.

With that set, the `<CR>` I pressed will be erased when I continue to type, if the length of current line is less than `lw`, and that is not what I want.

What I want is:

1. Still able to add a `<CR>` automatically if the line is longer than `lw`.
2. When I type a `<CR>` manually when the line length is less than `lw`, I don't want that `<CR>` erased when I continue to type.

Thanks.

Comment: Usually one would say by turning off the fo-=a option, but it would probably be better if you could describe what it is you're trying to do in the first place. Easier to grasp on an example.

Comment: How is `'lispwords'` option be compared to the line length? I guess you meant `'textwidth'` (**t**w) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The format option "a" is designed to reformat your paragraph every time your paragraph is changed, so there's no way for you to keep any single line breaks inside your paragraph, regarding the definition of "paragraph" in VIM.

If you only need to be able to wrap long lines while typing, you don't need option "a". Option "t" is already quite sufficient for your case.

```
t   Auto-wrap text using textwidth
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that's just what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with using trailing spaces to indicate that a paragraph continues (by default it only ends on an empty line) then you can also do

```
set fo+=w
```

. Then to keep vim from joining lines all you need is to end it with something other then a space.

Note: this is not going to change the meaning of the paragraph for motion commands (in fact, there is nothing that can do change it).